# Split a type string NUMBER to list of chars

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column which has alphanumeric strings like `123x758v961j`.

I need to split this alphanumeric number to chars an have blank space between values.

Example: `123x758v961j` =====> `1 2 3 x 7 5 8 v 9 6 1 j`

I need a function which returns this solution.

Comment: This was closed as duplicate, but the linked question was offering just outdated approaches using `WHILE` loops... Voted to re-open the question...

Answer (score 3):

Using [`NGrams8K`](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/) to split the string into individual characters and then the "classic" `FOR XML PATH` and `STUFF` solution to combine the characters back you can do this:

```
SELECT V.S,
       STUFF((SELECT ' ' + NG.token
              FROM dbo.NGrams8k(V.S,1) NG
              ORDER BY NG.position
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','varchar(100)'),1,1,'') AS S2 --Use a varchar length that is double(-1) then length of your actual data type here
FROM (VALUES('123x758v961j'))V(S);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just another way

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitToChars(
  @String NVARCHAR(300)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(300)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(300) = '';

  WITH CTE AS
  (
    SELECT 1 N
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N + 1
    FROM CTE
    WHERE N < LEN(@String)
  )
  SELECT @Result = CONCAT(@Result, SUBSTRING(@String, N, 1), N' ')
  FROM CTE;

  RETURN (RTRIM(@Result));
END;
```

Then just `SELECT dbo.SplitToChars(N'123x758v961j')`

**Returns:**

```
1 2 3 x 7 5 8 v 9 6 1 j
```

**[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0698d06dd77842f43a61fb55bca9968f)**

Answer (score 0):

And one more approach ;-)

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100)='123x758v961j';

WITH Tally(Nmbr) AS 
(
    SELECT TOP(LEN(@str)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values
)
SELECT TRIM(
            (
                SELECT ' ' + SUBSTRING(@str,Nmbr,1)
                FROM Tally
                ORDER BY Nmbr
                FOR XML PATH('')
            )
           );
```

The idea is, to use a *tally-on-the-fly* (a list of running numbers for each position within `@str`) to read the characters *one-by-one*. This derived table is reconcatenated.

And - just for fun - to demonstrate the range of approaches, one more using a *quirky update* (something to avoid actually ;-)  )

```
WITH Tally(Nmbr) AS 
(
    SELECT TOP(LEN(@str)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values
)
SELECT @str=STUFF(@str,Nmbr,0,' ')
FROM Tally
ORDER BY Nmbr DESC;

SELECT @str;
```